# VBA_BlackScholes_Greeks_Argument not optional Error:

Tags: excel, vba, macos, arguments, option-type

Argument not optional Error:

```vb
Function Delta_Blackscholes(Choix As String, X As Double, S As Double, T As Double, rf As Double, sigma As Double, y As Double) As Double

'Step 1 : Declaration des variables intermediaire
Dim d1 As Double
Dim ln As Double
'Step 2: Calculs intermédiaires
ln = Application.WorksheetFunction.ln(S / X)
d1 = (ln + (rf - y + 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * T) / (sigma * Sqr(T))
'Step 3: Outputs
If Choix = "Call" Then
' Le Delta du Call
Delta_Blackscholes = Exp(-y * T) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(d1)
' Le Delta du Put
ElseIf Choix = "Put" Then
Delta_Blackscholes = Exp(-y * T) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(-d1)
End If
```

Really don't know why, tried multiple time rewriting or changing the form

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(d1,cumulative)` requires a second parameter. If cumulative is TRUE, NORMS.DIST returns the cumulative distribution function; if FALSE, it returns the probability mass function. [see docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/norm-s-dist-function-1e787282-3832-4520-a9ae-bd2a8d99ba88).